# How can I get Underline and bullet positions in WPF RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

For a WPF RichTextBox, is there a way to obtain

- the co-ordinates of the text decorations, such as the stroke applied for Underlining?
- the co-ordinates as well as the shape\character used for bullets in bulleted list?